# Link and image nicely aligned in a Bootstrap card header

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap card that looks like this (relevant styles moved inline for ease of viewing):

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
<h5 class="card-header" ><a href="#">Card Link</a><img src="logo.png" style="max-height: 1.5em;max-width: 1.5em;"></h5>
  <div class="card-body">
    Card Body Text
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have the link on the left side of the header, and the image on the right side. If the link fits on one line, the image should be vertically aligned to the middle of the link text. If it is multiple lines, the image should be vertically aligned to the middle of the top line of text. Alternatively, just top aligned should look OK.

I'm not sure of the right Bootstrap way to achieve this without causing other issues.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34ufrnxb/).

Answer (score 1):

float the image to the right to get what you want, like in the snippet below:

```css
img{
  max-height: 1.5rm;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
<h5 class="card-header" >
<img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" >
<a href="#">Card Link that is very very very long</a>
</h5>
  <div class="card-body">
    Card Body Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And switch the positions so that the image comes before the link! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

So easy to achieve that with *flexbox*.

You can set the `.card-header` as the flexbox. Remember to set it `nowrap` and `space-between` justify so that its children the link and the image would stay left and right.

`align-items` controls the vertical alignment. If you want top alignment, set it to `flex-start`. Center alignment could be achieved by setting it to `center`.

```css
.card-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <h5 class="card-header">
        <a href="#">Card Link</a>
        <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="max-height: 1.5em; max-width: 1.5em;">
    </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        Card Body Text
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <h5 class="card-header">
        <a href="#">Card Link with multiple lines of text</a>
        <img src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" style="max-height: 1.5em; max-width: 1.5em;">
    </h5>
    <div class="card-body">
        Card Body Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Optionally you can achieve the same thing just by adding *[bootstrap flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)* classes to the `.card-header`, without writing any custom css I wrote above.